# Are there any rules about which fruits may not be consumed during a fast?

Tags: scripture, fasting

The set of fruits in common circulation must have changed over time with contact with other cultures and experimentation for breeding new strains. As such do the scriptures say anything about which fruits are to not be consumed during a fast?

Comment: All fruits are Sattvik.

Comment: @Rāmadāsa Please offer some scriptural statements to that effect. Also you can put it as an answer.